# Show linear operator $L$ has no eigenvalue, i.e. there exist no $\lambda \in \mathbb R$ and $f \in C(\mathbb R,\mathbb R)$ s.t. $L(f) = \lambda f$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $C(\mathbb R,\mathbb R)$ denote the real vectorspace of continuous real functions on $\mathbb R$.

Let $L: C(\mathbb R,\mathbb R) \rightarrow C(\mathbb R,\mathbb R)$ denote the function $L(f)(x) = \int^x_0 f(t) dt$.

I've shown that $L$ is a linear operator by using the fundamental theorem of calculus and shown $L(af+bg)(x) = aL(f)(x) + bL(f)(x)$ for $a,b \in \mathbb R$.

However I must show that $L$ has no eigenvalue, i.e. there exist no $\lambda \in \mathbb R$ and $f \in C(\mathbb R,\mathbb R)$ such that $L(f) = \lambda f$.

How can I show this ?

Comment: Do you plan to delete the present post after it gets some answers, as you deleted [this other post](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/768620/6179) with neither warning nor explanation?

Answer (score 4):

Assume a function $f\neq 0$ is an eigenvector for some $\lambda\neq 0$.
Then you obtain $L(f)=\lambda f$.
If you derive the equation, you get $f=\lambda f'$. This is a well-known differential equation, and the solutions are all the functions of the form $f(x)=Ae^{\lambda x}$ with $A\in\mathbb R$.

But we know that $f(0)=\frac{L(f)(0)}{\lambda}=0$, so we obtain $A=0$ and therefore $f=0$. We reach a contradiction.

Comment: How do you know $f$ has an derivative ? It is just continuous.

Comment: because $f=L(f)/\lambda$ and $L(f)$ obviously has a derivative which is $f$.

Comment: Ahh, could you also just take the limit on both sides and then put the constant $\lambda$ outside the limit and then argue that  the limit of $f$ must exist ?

Comment: You dropped the case that $\lambda=0$ in the beginning, but $L(f)=\lambda f$ applies then as well and then $L(f)=0$ implies $f=0$.

Comment: why does it imply f=0? f(x)-f(0)=0 but how do we know f(0)=0?